# Jenkins build agent appears offline but agent service is up and Running

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I am having trouble that Jenkins home page shows the Build agent is offline. But when I actually log in to build agent server, the agent service is up and running.

I am using Windows 2003 OS for all my Build agent and controller server. The only way to get it online is to restart the service again.

Comment: After restarting the master node our problem gone away.

Answer (score 5):

Follow the given steps, you will not required to restart the services.

```
Goto Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes
```

This will show you the list configured nodes.
In which

```
Build Slave -> Launch Slave Agent (Where "Build Slave" is your slave node.)
```

This will work if your `slave` is configured properly and connected with the services.

Comment: Hi Kishan, Thanks for the help. I wonder why this is happening do you have guess where i can find the reason for this. I think if the slave is up and running Master should not show it is off line.

Comment: @user3164236 Master Jenkins server constantly checks for the slave or other configured node connections in background. you can find the connection problem in log of nodes. for example your node is `Demo_Slave` than you can view this log at `Jenkins -> Nodes -> Demo_Slave -> Log`. you will find reason in that log.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue: JNLP slave agent is launched and shows connected state, but jenkins server shows slave as offline. The only entry in the slave log is `JNLP agent connected from /10.0.0.134` and the spinning icon. The only thing that helped the last time is the restart of jenkins/apache.

Comment: Update: I upgraded to 1.561 and the issue seems to be fixed (for now). I'll keep an eye on it nevertheless...

Comment: I have 1.571 running and the same issue. The server logs also the accepted connection but the ui still tells me that the slave is offline...

Comment: Same problem with a Jenkins 1.629, and suggested actions do not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins master need communicate with Slave with ssh connection if master and slave are not in the same node.
Double check if master's ssh public key is in slave's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.